# google map plugin cordova not load getMap()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova

Everything worked before. But suddenly it's showing white screen and throwing this below error.

> `getMap` is not defined

[image]

[image]

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="'26.0.2'" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=26 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=26 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you start Google maps api from google developer console

Comment: Yes, I'm start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency section of `platform/android/app/build.gradle` is probably like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.1.0"
    compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

The problem is some plugin specifies `+`, but the maps plugin specifies `12.0.0` (or maybe other versions)

The version number `+` is very danger keyword.
The gradle use the latest version at the build time when you specified `+`, but it does not work sometimes. That's why the maps plugin specifies particular version, but you can specify the version with `--variable`.

You need to modify the `build.grale` file. Specify the same version of all dependencies that use Google Play Services SDK.

For example:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.1.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:12.0.1"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:12.0.1"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:12.0.1"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

By the way `com.google.gms:google-services:+` installs all packages. This increases apk file size. And it causes troubles. I recommend to remove it.

**update:**
Also `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` should be removed because of the same reason.

Comment: Ohhh It work. I'm just specified version in libs.  I followed you and remove classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'. I just specify a version in the libs and modify it in a little build.grale to work all together.    edit : I am very happy to receive your reply . Thx for the plugin.  sry! My English isn't that good.